# My pagination doesnt work in wordpress custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, function, pagination, blogs

I am using pagination_bar from function.php. I implemented that in custom page called page-blog.php. I restriced pages to only 2 per page and i have 3 blog posts. After I put pagination_bar() function it shows me fatal error.

I saw some soluton already here but none of them helps. I have tried doing some offset.

function.php

```
function pagination_bar() {
    global $wp_query;

    $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => 'page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text' => '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
            'next_text' => '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
        ));
    }
}
```

page-blog.php

```
             <div class="col-xl-8 col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 md-blog-posts">

                        <?php 

                            $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;


                            $homePagePosts = new WP_Query(array(
                                'posts_per_page' => '2',
                                'post_type'   => 'post',
                                'has_archive' =>  true,
                                'post_status' =>  'publish',
                                'order'       =>  'DESC',
                                'paged' => $paged,


                            ));
                        if($homePagePosts->have_posts()) :
                            while($homePagePosts->have_posts()) :
                            $homePagePosts->the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 md-blog-blog">
                                <div class="md-blog-img">
                                        <div class="img-container">
                                            <div class="positioning">
                                                <span class="md-blogdate-number"><?php the_time('F d, Y.'); ?></span>
                                                <h4 class="md-blog-title"><?php echo get_the_title() ?></h4>
                                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn md-button-read-more" id="md-blog-button">Read More</a> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="md-blog-img"><?php  the_post_thumbnail() ?></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php endwhile;  ?>


                         <?php else : ?>

                            <h1>There is no posts at this moment</h1>

                         <?php endif; ?>

                         <div class="md-pagination-holder" style="background: #333; width:50px; height: 50px; color: #fff;">            
                            <?php paginate_bar(); ?>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

Also you can see the website here - > http://prodenvermovers.wpupkeep.org/blog/

I get fatal error.

EDIT : http://prntscr.com/oij1dr

I chaned paginate_bar to pagination_bar as function is actually called but i get error above when i refresh the page.

Comment: First off, you shouldn't set an offset and a pagination.  The offset breaks this functionality.  You only need the "paged" parameter.  Remove the "offset".

Comment: I did all what you told me and still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to see if you can get the page to work.  In this example it just uses the built in WP hooks to generate pagination links.  Also, by "still not working" do you mean you are still getting the error, or just not seeing the pagination?

```
             <div class="col-xl-8 col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 md-blog-posts">

                        <?php 

                            $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;


                            $homePagePosts = new WP_Query(array(
                                'posts_per_page' => '2',
                                'post_type'   => 'post',
                                'has_archive' =>  true,
                                'post_status' =>  'publish',
                                'order'       =>  'DESC',
                                'paged' => $paged,


                            ));
                        if($homePagePosts->have_posts()) :
                            while($homePagePosts->have_posts()) :
                            $homePagePosts->the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 md-blog-blog">
                                <div class="md-blog-img">
                                        <div class="img-container">
                                            <div class="positioning">
                                                <span class="md-blogdate-number"><?php the_time('F d, Y.'); ?></span>
                                                <h4 class="md-blog-title"><?php echo get_the_title() ?></h4>
                                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn md-button-read-more" id="md-blog-button">Read More</a> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="md-blog-img"><?php  the_post_thumbnail() ?></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php endwhile;  ?>
                               <div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>

                               <div class="nav-next alignright"><?php next_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>

                         <?php else : ?>

                            <h1>There is no posts at this moment</h1>

                         <?php endif; ?>


                </div>
```

Comment: Not seeing the pagination. I cant see it at all

Comment: You can check it on ProMoversDev page. Its live and im coding it right now. Ill try this solution that u gave me and we will see if it works.

Comment: Check the webpage - >  http://prodenvermovers.wpupkeep.org/blog/  Where it says asd there should be previous alignleft button but it wont show up still...

Comment: Also I would love to aks you one more question. Can we instead of newer and older posts put pages? Like paginate_links() ? I have tried but thats not working either

Comment: You can write whatever you want in that hook.  So for example, <?php previous_posts_link( 'Yesterday' ) ?>.  Is that what you're asking?